# Game Audio for beginners

Tags: game, sound-design, tutorial

Hi!

Do you guys have anything to recommend in terms of tutorials for game audio?

I was searching through the web and could only find a very small smount of info about UDK, pretty much nothing about WWISE and FMOD. Is there anything you could advise to go and read in those terms? Book? Tutorial?

Anything to get started would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [AudioKinetics Wwise](http://www.audiokinetic.com/en/learning-center/videos) and [Firelight's FMOD](http://www.fmod.org) have a load of information and tutorials on websites. Youtube is one of the best resources for learning the API's too, this is what I got when searching for [FMOD](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=fmod&aq=f).
As for general game audio specific stuff try [Gamasutra's](http://www.gamasutra.com/php-bin/article_display.php) game audio articles - they are usually very informative, and written by people who really know their stuff :)
hope this helps -

Answer (score 1):

I personally do best when I am paying money to learn and have a deadline and professor (I am sure it has to do with my cheap money obsessed nature.)  So...I have been eyeballing this Berklee online course http://www.berkleemusic.com/school/course?course_item_id=8688817&usca_p=t&offer_code=2285.

If anyone out there has taken it and can review. Please do.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Richard! I must be going blind and somehow I missed the big "Learning Center" button on AudioKinetics site!!

I will share some of the stuff that i found myself:

FMOD:

http://www.fmod.org/wiki/index.php5?title=Main_Page

http://www.fmod.org/forum/

http://www.gamesounddesign.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=241

http://www.freebasic.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=11

http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article2098.asp

UDK:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPlHGPhcBOs&p=A4CBC7A0D6909ED6&playnext=1&index=36

So there is quite a big hole in UDK tutorials. In most UDK books that I had a look at there is a chapter about audio... if you're lucky it's about 1,5/2 pages.. :)
Anyone has some ideas with UDK?

Answer (score 0):

some more good stuff

http://www.youtube.com/user/FMODTV

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's going to shape into a nice resource, and the upcoming ebook sounds neat.

http://www.gameaudio101.com/